if $E_{sep}/F$ is normal then $E/F$ is normal. Or give a counter-example.
Let $E/F$ be an algebraic field extension, denote $E_{sep}$ by the separable closure of $F$ in $E$.
We know if $E/F$ is normal then $E_{sep}/F$ is normal, see tag 0EXK. The reverse should be false and I want an example. As noted in the comments, $E/E_{sep}$ is always normal.
Here is what I thought: Let $F=\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ and $m(x)$ be a degree $n$ irreducible separable polynomial with distinct roots $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$, e.g. $m(x)=x^n-t$ with $p\nmid n$, then $F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)/F$ is normal and separable. Let $E=F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n,\alpha_1^{1/p})$ so $E/F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ is purely inseparable of degree $p$ and thus $E_{sep}=F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$.
Then the normal closure of $E/F$ is $F(\alpha_1^{1/p},\dots,\alpha_n^{1/p})$ which should generally be strictly bigger than $F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n,\alpha_1^{1/p})$, implying that $E/F$ is not normal. But I have difficulties showing this for any explicit example.
Update: I'm now thinking about $m(x)=x^3+bx+c\in F[x]$ with $p>3$ and the discriminant $D=-4b^3-27c^2\notin F^2$, so $m(x)$ is irreducible and separable. Let $\alpha=\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ be the roots of $m$ in $\overline{F}$, then $F(\alpha,\sqrt{D})=F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ is a splitting field of $m$ over $F$, see this calculation. Similarly it's not hard to see that the normal closure of $F(\alpha,\sqrt{D},\alpha^{1/p})$ is $F(\alpha_1^{1/p},\alpha_2^{1/p},\alpha_3^{1/p})=F(\alpha^{1/p},D^{1/2p})$. It remains to show that $D^{1/2p}\notin F(\alpha^{1/p},\sqrt{D})$.
An answer has been posted in Math.Overflow, see here.

$(\alpha_i^{1/p})^n$ is the $p$-th root of $t$, which shows that the $\alpha_i^{1/p}$ differ multiplicatively by an $n$-th root of unity. Since the same is true for the $\alpha_ i$, the field $F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ already has the $n$-th roots of unity. This implies that $F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n,\alpha_1^{1/p})$ contains all the other $\alpha_i^{1/p}$, hence is equal to $F(\alpha_1^{1/p},\dots,\alpha_n^{1/p})$. So unfortunately, this example does not work.

I feel like every element of $E$ outside of $E_{sep}$ should be a $p$-power root of something in $E_{sep}$, and hence $E/E_{sep}$ is normal no matter what...

@FrançoisGatine You are right. $E/E_{sep}$ is always normal, but a composite of normal extension may not be normal, so $E/F$ could be non-normal when $E_{sep}/F$ is normal, which is what I want an example for.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Mor}{Mor}\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}$Suppose $E_{sep}/F$ is normal. Choose an algebraic closure $\overline{F}$ of $F$. Pick an element $\sigma_{0}\in\Mor_{F}(E,\overline{F})$. Consider the following commutative diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Aut(E/F) @>{\tau\mapsto\sigma_{0}\circ\tau}>> \Mor_{F}(E,\overline{F})\\
@VV{\tau\mapsto\tau|_{E_{sep}}}V @VV{\tau\mapsto\tau|_{E_{sep}}}V \\
\Aut(E_{sep}/F) @>{\tau\mapsto\sigma_{0}|_{E_{sep}}\circ\tau}>> \Mor_{F}(E_{sep},\overline{F})
\end{CD}$$
The left arrow is well-defined as $E_{sep}/F$ is normal and is surjective as $E/E_{sep}$ is normal, see tag 0BME. It's not hard to see that the right arrow is bijective, e.g. see the proof of tag 09HJ. The top arrow is clearly injective. The bottom arrow is bijective because $E_{sep}/F$ is normal, see tag 09HQ and the proof of tag 09HS.
By simple diagram chase we can see that all the arrows are bijective, in particular the top arrow is bijective. Then for all $\sigma\in\Mor_{F}(E,\overline{F}), \sigma(E)=\sigma_{0}(E)$ and thus $E/F$ is normal by tag 09HQ.

Update: The answer is false as the left arrow maynot be surjective.
